# Linq OrderBy depending on condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I want to order a list depending on the result of

```
if(group.Substring(group.Length-1,1)%2==0)
```

order descending
 `else` 
order ascending

```
List<CellTemp> orderedCells = 
        (from shelf in foundCells
         where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1), 1) % 2 == 0
         orderby shelf.Grup, shelf.Row descending
         select new CellTemp()
         {
             cod= shelf.cod,
             PN = shelf.PN,
             Description = shelf.Description,
             Group= shelf.Group,
             Row= shelf.Row,
             Shelf= shelf.Shelf
         }).ToList();
```

How can I keep the first shelf.Group OrderBy and OrderBy shelf.row ascending or descending depending if shelf.Group is odd or even ?

The format of shelf.group is "Group_A0".

--------------------Edited---------------------------

Sorry for the confusion. I want to do something like this.

```
var orderCells = (from shelf in celuleGasite
  where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Gruup.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 0
  orderby shelf.Group, shelf.Row descending
  where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 1
  orderby shelf.Group, shelf.Row ascending 
  select shelf).ToList();
```

but the list is has 0 elements

Comment: The statement is to long to make it easy to read and maintain. If you store al subqueries in a single variable with a clear name, then it would be easier to answer the question also.

Comment: @GeorgesC what is the type of your `shelf.Row`?

Comment: shelf.Row is string in this format "Row_1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
 var orderCells = (from shelf in celuleGasite
     where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 0
     orderby shelf.Group, shelf.Row descending)
     .Concat(from shelf in celuleGasite
             where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 1
             orderby shelf.Group, shelf.Row)
     .ToList();
```

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
var orderCells = celuleGasite.GroupBy(shelf=>Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group[shelf.Group.Length-1]) % 2)
                             .Select(g=>g.Key == 0 ? g.OrderBy(shelf=>shelf.Group)
                                                      .ThenByDescending(shelf=>shelf.Row) :
                                                     g.OrderBy(shelf=>shelf.Group)
                                                      .ThenBy(shelf=>shelf.Row))
                             .SelectMany(x=>x)
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'm starting now to make it work. As you see here  [link](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/1487/tbjc.jpg) it is not correctly sorted. It should be ordered by "Grup" and if the last number of the Grup is odd then the Raft with the same Grup should be ordered descending.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of King King I managed to find the solution. His code probably was written from head :) so If you're stuck like I was, here is the complete code.

```
 var orderCells1 = (from shelf in foundCells
            where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 0
            orderby shelf.Row descending
            select shelf).Concat(from shelf in foundCells
            where Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group.Substring(shelf.Group.Length - 1, 1)) % 2 == 1
            orderby shelf.Row
            select shelf).OrderBy(grup => grup.Group).ToList();
```

Or using GroupBy

```
var orderCells2 = foundCells.GroupBy(shelf=>Convert.ToInt32(shelf.Group[shelf.Group.Length - 1]) % 2)
  .Select(g => g.Key == 0 ? 
               g.OrderByDescending(shelf => shelf.Row) : g.OrderBy(shelf => shelf.Row))
  .SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(group=>group.Group).ToList();
```